# Why is a script tag deleted automatically by Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, jsonp, script-tag

everyone.

I don't use jQuery. I create a `script` tag and append it to `head` tag to get JSONP data. After JSONP callback function is executed, the `script` tag which is just added to `head` tag by me is automatically deleted by browser (Chrome). Why is the script tag deleted automatically by Chrome? I don't write any codes to delete this `script` tag.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it's being removed?

Comment: I see the dynamic DOM in Google Chrome's developer tools. I see the `script` tag is added by my codes, then JSONP callback function is run, then the `script` tag is deleted automatically by Chrome (not my codes).

Comment: See my reply to your comment on my answer.

Comment: Once the code is executed, it doesn't matter that the element is removed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't. The most common reason people think DOM changes aren't being done is that they look at "view source" rather than the actual DOM panel. Be sure that when you're looking for it, you're looking at the "Elements" tab in the Dev Tools. "View source" shows you the original HTML delivered from the server, not the DOM and any modifications you may have made to it.

**If** the element is really going away, there is code removing it. Chrome doesn't arbitrarily remove `script` elements ([proof](http://jsbin.com/okoceg)). Some possibilities:

1. Other code on the page is removing it.
2. You've added it as a descendant element of something, and its parent (or ancestor) is being removed.
3. You've added it as a descendant element of something, and then you're updating that parent/ancestor element with new content, replacing its previous content (e.g., via `innerHTML` or similar).

In 2 and 3 above, the code is removing the `script` element as a by-product of removing or updating its parent/ancestor.

Comment: I see the dynamic DOM in Google Chrome's developer tools. I see the `script` tag is added by my codes, then JSONP callback function is run, then the `script` tag is deleted automatically by Chrome (not my codes).

Comment: @WeiLou: If it is really going away, *something* is removing it, and it isn't Chrome. It may not be *your* code, but there **is** code on the page removing it. Chrome does not arbitrarily remove `script` elements.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm look for codes that delete my `script` tag. Thank you for help!

Comment: im actually getting the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out, I think jQuery is doing something behind the scenes to remove dynamic scripts. If I don't include jQuery on the page, it stays in the DOM. However, the new versions of jQuery (1.9.0 and above) don't produce this problem.